# Authorization header - token only?

Tags: rest, authorization, access-token

I'm implementing REST-like API and I want to add authorization with access tokens. I know that there are 2 different ways to pass token from client to server:

1. **Authorization** header
2. **/api/example?token=** as query param

It's all simple and nice with 2nd option - simply grab whatever value **token** query param provides and use it.

Where with authorization header it's a little bit more complicated - instead of simply adding token as a value I see specs and other implementations use prefix "Bearer" in a form of "Bearer **token**"

Suppose I don't care about what spec says and my API could be consumed with only a single authorization strategy - do I loose anything if I omit "Bearer" and provide only **token** value?

I just don't see point in adding additional effort to parse string on a server just to get token while I can simply send only token value. Do I miss something here?

Answer (score 0):

I think that this link could help you: https://templth.wordpress.com/2015/01/05/implementing-authentication-with-tokens-for-restful-applications/.

I think that you are free to put what you want within the header `Authorization`. That said, not following specs (OAuth) prevents you from using standard processing for client REST libraries...

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Answer (score 0):

You have two possibilities:

1. You treat the header `Authorization` like any other header following https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.2 and you can pass any value and retrieve it programmatically as you would do with any other header. But you could use any header then, you don't have to specifically use `Authorization`. You just have to give the correct information to the consumers of your API.
2. You respect the RFC for `Authorization` (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7235#appendix-C ) and you prefix your token with a valid `auth-scheme`, simplest is `Basic` but here's a list : https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-authschemes/http-authschemes.xhtml and when you retrieve your header, you simply strip the `auth-scheme` and the space before your token.

In your case, if you choose the second solution, use `Basic` because you don't use any specific protocol or framework for your authentication.
`Bearer` is used for token provided by the OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750.html). Usually `Basic` is used with a `username/password` pair encoded using Base64 (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7617.html) but your API will be reponsible to decode it so it could be any token.

ex: `Authorization: Basic <yourtoken>`